# undefined method `cattr_accessor' for RailsUpgrade::Upgraders::RouteRedrawer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was upgrading a Rails 2 application to Rails 3.
Then I installed `rails-upgrade` gem:

```
$ gem install rails-upgrade --user-install
Fetching: rails-upgrade-0.0.2.gem (100%)
PostInstall.txt
Successfully installed rails-upgrade-0.0.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-upgrade-0.0.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-upgrade-0.0.2...
```

And then I ran `check`, but it raise this error:

```
$ rails-upgrade check
/home/neoriddle/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-upgrade-0.0.2/lib/rails-upgrade/upgraders/routes.rb:28: undefined method `cattr_accessor' for RailsUpgrade::Upgraders::RouteRedrawer:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/neoriddle/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-upgrade-0.0.2/lib/rails-upgrade.rb:12
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/neoriddle/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-upgrade-0.0.2/bin/rails-upgrade:7
    from /home/neoriddle/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/rails-upgrade:19:in `load'
    from /home/neoriddle/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/rails-upgrade:19
```

What is wrong and how can I solve it?

I have installed Rails 3 and all dependencies required:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.9
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux]
$ gem list active

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

active_scaffold_vho (3.0.20)
activemerchant (1.15.0, 1.14.0)
activemodel (3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.5, 3.0.3)
activerecord (3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.3, 2.3.11, 2.3.5, 2.2.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.0.5, 1.15.3)
activeresource (3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.3, 2.3.11, 2.3.5, 2.2.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1)
activesupport (3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.5, 3.0.3, 2.3.11, 2.3.5, 2.2.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.0.5, 1.4.2)
$ gem list action

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.3, 2.3.11, 2.3.5, 2.2.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 1.3.3)
actionpack (3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.3, 2.3.11, 2.3.5, 2.2.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 1.13.3)
actionwebservice (1.2.6, 1.2.3)
```

If you need more infor please ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this gem has been updated to be compatible with Rails 3. The only other alternative is grabbing yourself a copy of the [Rails 3 Upgrade Handbook](http://rails3upgradehandbook.com) and using that to go through the upgrade process.

I wrote a blog post about upgrading a Rails 2 application to Rails 3 here: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/11/the-rails-3-upgrade/.

Comment: It has not been easy and I can't get a complete solution yet.